# ArrayList causing NullPointerException

Tags: java, swing, arraylist, nullpointerexception

I am getting nullpointer exception on this code from the paintcomponent method

```
  public A1Panel() {
            final ArrayList<MySnowFlake> myShapes = new ArrayList<MySnowFlake>();   //Stage 1: Replace this line
            popup = new JPopupMenu();               //create the popup menu
            makePopupMenu();

            addMouseListener( new MouseAdapter() {
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                maybeShowPopup(e);
            }

            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
                maybeShowPopup(e);
            }

            private void maybeShowPopup(MouseEvent e) {
                if (e.isPopupTrigger()) {
                    popup.show(e.getComponent(), e.getX(), e.getY());
                }
            }
            public void mouseClicked( MouseEvent e ) {  //Stage 1: Modify the following statements
                myShapes.add(currentIndex, new MySnowFlake(e.getX(), e.getY(), currentLevel, currentLength));
                currentIndex += 1;
                repaint();
            }
            });
        }

        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                //g.drawString("" + currentIndex, 50,50);
            //Stage 1: Modify the following statements
            try{
            for (int i = 0; i < currentIndex; i++) {
                myShapes.get(i).paint(g);
            }
            } catch(NullPointerException e){
                System.out.println("NullPointerException caught!!");
            }
        }
```

### MySnowFlake

```
public class MySnowFlake {
    protected int level;            // the recursion level
    protected Turtle turtle;        // the turtle object
    protected double turn = Math.PI/3; // the turning angle
    public int length;              // the length of the snowflake
    public Point p;                 // the initial position


    /** Constructor to create a Snowflake and initialize all values
    */
    public MySnowFlake(int x, int y, int level, int length) {
        this.level = level;
        this.length = length;
        p = new Point(x,y);
        turtle = new Turtle();
    }

    public void translate(int dx, int dy){
        p.x += dx;
        p.y += dy;
    }

    public void LevelUp(){
        level++;
    }

    public void LevelDown(){
        level--;
    }


    /**
     * Recursive draw method
    * @param lev -  the level of the koch shape
    * @param size -  the size of the koch shape
    */
    public void draw(int lev, double size) {
        // 1) define the base case
        if(lev < 0){

        // 2) define the recursive case

    }

    /**
     * Paint a snowflake
    * @param g  the graphics control
    */

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        double size = length;

        // replace this line with recursive calls
        g.drawRect(p.x, p.y, level*5, level*5);


        // 1) set up the turtle object first

        // 2) call the recursive draw method


    }
}
```

Comment: In catch block also print stacktrace and show it here.

Comment: Where is `currentIndex` declared and defined?

Comment: Where is myShapes declared? The one in the constructor is a local final variable..

Comment: do you call A1Panel() before paintComponent() ?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: After getting that code to compile, I see no run-time errors.  Please stop wasting everybody's time and ***post an SSCCE*** that shows the problem.

Comment: @AndrewThompson thanks for the warning I was about to do exactly the same. Please post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) and Ive got a feeling that commenting out `myShapes.get(i).paint(g);` stops this `NullPointerException`? well than something is wrong in your `MySnowFlake` class i.e something has not been initialized or something, if not its the loop (but I doubt that as long as `currentindex` and `myShapes` are initialized).

Answer (score 2):

The loop would work more reliable, when you would use the actual length of the ArrayList:

```
for (int i = 0; i < myShapes.size(); i++) {
```

But note that the exception could also occur inside the paint method of the class MySnowFlake. When you catch an exception which can be caused by a lot of different problems (like a NullPointerException), you should always print the stack trace of it so you can see where the exception is actually thrown:

```
        } catch(NullPointerException e){
            System.out.println("NullPointerException caught!!");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

In production software it is usually a good idea to save the stack-traces of all unexpected exceptions to a logfile or a database so you can do a post-mortem analysis later.

Comment: That depends on the reason for the NPE. That's why you should print a stack-trace.

Comment: I have commented this before you update. This is On side note using better approach for iterating a list. Surely this is no where is the answer.

Comment: This is a comment not an answer!

Comment: Thanks, I am still getting nullpointerexceptions though, I have included MySnowFlake class

Comment: can you tell us where youget the exception? maybe you can show us the complete error message?

Comment: so it is line 96 in A1Panel. Could you please paste line 96 in your questiona bove?

Comment: for (int i = 0; i < myShapes.size() - 1; i++) {

Answer (score 0):

Could you please change the sequence of these 2 lines, i.e. instead of

```
myShapes.add(currentIndex, new MySnowFlake(e.getX(), e.getY(), currentLevel, currentLength));
currentIndex += 1;
```

try this:

```
currentIndex += 1;
myShapes.add(currentIndex, new MySnowFlake(e.getX(), e.getY(), currentLevel, currentLength));
```

Comment: for (int i = 0; i < myShapes.size() - 1; i++) {

Comment: sorry, I caught a arrayoutofbounds exception

Comment: When currentIndex is initialized as 0 and you increment it before adding the first element, then this should leave index 0 empty and start at index 1. This should immediately cause a NPE when looping over the array.